# custompostback __dopostback not firing from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

So I've built a live search box that updates on keyup. It populates a span with items that match the string input as the user types.

I am trying to dynamically create links using anchor tags so that when a user clicks one of the results in the pop up results span, it takes the users employee number and does a customer postback where it is picked up server side.

Javascript function that runs on keyup to build the results span:

```
   function liveSearch() {
            //debugger;
            $("#<%= QuickNameSearch_error.ClientID %>").text("");
            $("#<%= QuickNameSearch_error.ClientID %>").hide("");
            var searchField = $("#<%= QuickNameSearch_textbox.ClientID %>").val();
            if (searchField.length == 0) {
                $("#QuickNameSearchResults").hide();
                return;
            }
            else {
                $("#QuickNameSearchResults").show();
            }
            var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
            var output = '<div class="liveSearchOuter">';
            var count = 0;
            $.getJSON('Scripts/LiveSearchData.js', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    try {
                        if ((val.preferred.search(regex)) != -1 || (val.surname.search(regex) != -1)) {
                            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                                output += '<div class="liveSearchItem liveSearchItemLight">';
                            }
                            else {
                                output += '<div class="liveSearchItem liveSearchItemDark">';
                            }
                            output += "<div><b><a id='hlEmpName" + count + "' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='CustomPostBack('" + val.emp_no.trim() + "');'>" + val.preferred.trim() + " " + val.surname.trim() + "</a></b></div>";
                            output += "<div><b><a id='hlEmpEmail" + count + "' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='CustomPostBack('" + val.emp_no.trim() + "');'>" + val.email.trim() + "</a></b></div>";

                            output += '</div>';
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
                if (count == 0) {
                    output += '<div class="liveSearchItem liveSearchItemLight"><div>No results found</div>';
                }
                output += '</div>';
                $("#QuickNameSearchResults").html(output);
            });
        }

        function CustomPostBack(argStr) {
            debugger;
            __doPostBack('CustomPostBack', argStr);
        }
```

C# function that runs on pageload:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if ((Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "CustomPostBack") && (Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] != ""))
            {
                string eventTarget = Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
                string eventArgument = Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
                ShowEmployeeProfile(eventArgument.Trim());
            }
        }
```

I've used custom postbacks before in javascript to great effect, but never from an anchor tag. I've read on here it is possible, but I can't see where I'm going wrong and I have been reading questions and answers for hours.

The main two lines that I'm having trouble with are:

```
output += "<div><b><a id='hlEmpName" + count + "' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='CustomPostBack('" + val.emp_no.trim() + "');'>" + val.preferred.trim() + " " + val.surname.trim() + "</a></b></div>";
output += "<div><b><a id='hlEmpEmail" + count + "' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='CustomPostBack('" + val.emp_no.trim() + "');'>" + val.email.trim() + "</a></b></div>";
```

I have tried a hundred variations of small changes. They render to this when run:

```
<a id="hlEmpName0" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="CustomPostBack(" 123456');'="">Testy McTest</a>
```

The page does not post back though and reach the page load to catch the employee number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like your quotes are a little screwy. Take a look at your last snippet:

```
onclick="CustomPostBack(" 845169");"
```

Your `onclick` is being cut short because you're using double-quotes for your parameters. The browser sees it as `onclick="CustomPostBack("` and the remaining portion is just text in the middle of nowhere.

If this value is always going to be a number, just remove the quotes around it altogether:

```
output += '<div><b><a id="hlEmpName' + count + '" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="CustomPostBack(' + val.emp_no.trim() + ');">' + val.preferred.trim() + ' ' + val.surname.trim() + '</a></b></div>';
```

If it needs to be a string value then you can escape your single-quotes by doing `&apos;` instead of `"`:

```
output += '<div><b><a id="hlEmpName' + count + '" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="CustomPostBack(&apos;' + val.emp_no.trim() + '&apos;);">' + val.preferred.trim() + ' ' + val.surname.trim() + '</a></b></div>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually played around with switching the double and single quotes but didn't know about escaping quotes, hence didn't know what to search for and didn't know what I was doing wrong! Apologies for being incredible slow today :-)

Comment: Not a problem! I changed `&quot;` to `&apos;` - let me know how this works for you. If it doesn't work as you expect, just post the updated "rendered version" (your last snippet) for me and I'll continue. Otherwise, if it *does* work, be sure to mark the answer as accepted so future readers can find the answer they're looking for! :)